# Performance of open SSL on large text

Tags: c, linux, openssl

I am currently using openSSL on linux c. I would like to ask if the cipher block size is always fixed to 16 unsigned char? The reason for this is because I am encrypting a massively large data. The problem is based on the description of SSL, the ecrypted cipher block of the previous block is XOR to the next plain text block when encrypting. Is there a way to icrease the size of the cipher block?

For example if I had a Gigabyte of data to encrypt, it would take Gigabyte/16byte times of encryption. Is there a standard way to force the AES_cbc_encrypt method call to use a vi that is not 16 byte? The still follows the standard? The reason for this is the encrypted text would be read by another program on another system that uses another CGC standard library.

Comment: Sounds like a case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the AES standard mandates a 16 byte block size. The original algorithm which it was based on, Rijndael, allowed more flexibility, but you can't rely on another AES implementation to support that.

Answer (score 1):

For block ciphers, the size of the block is the property of the algorithm in question. DES used 8 bytes for instance. Stream ciphers (RC4 for example) on the other hand do not use fixed block sizes, they are effectively pseudo random generators seeded with the key.

But anyway,  the performance of ciphers are published with the block size in mind, and AES does about 160mbyte/sec on a recent CPU. You can measure this using "openssl speed aes".

So, if you want to encrypt 1Gb of data, I'd be more concerned with moving all that data from disk, to memory and back again, rather than the encryption speed of AES itself.